# Find best-matched line from a text file using keywords. Sort of works, but not perfect, how do I fix?

Tags: c#

I have been trying to get this to work for the past two hours with quite a lot of success but it is not working 100%. It auto suggests lines from the file to the nearest 1-2 words I believe which is not what I want. I want it to suggest it as best as possible.

An example is here: https://gyazo.com/6cb86e78b95026aeeb3f8cc96ca03163

As you can see, it gives me two suggestions in the console but prints the right one to me due to where it is placed in the text document. Howcome it is not giving me the only one I want even though it's word-for-word and therefore has more keywords in common than the one without stattrak.

This is my code:

```
string[] suggestContents = File.ReadAllLines("csgo_items.txt");
int lineCount = 0;
int mostSimilar = 0;
int currentSimilar = 0;
string[] splitLine = message.Split("_".ToCharArray());
Dictionary<int, int> suggestItem = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (string line in suggestContents)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < splitLine.Length; i++)
    {
        if(line.ToLower().Contains(splitLine[i].ToLower()))
        {
            currentSimilar++;
        }
    }
    if(currentSimilar > mostSimilar)
    {
        List<int> suggestList = new List<int>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> entry in suggestItem)
        {
            if(entry.Value == mostSimilar)
            {
                suggestList.Add(entry.Key);
            }
        }
        foreach(int intRemove in suggestList)
        {
            suggestItem.Remove(intRemove);
        }
        mostSimilar = currentSimilar;
        suggestItem.Add(lineCount, mostSimilar);
    }
    else if(currentSimilar == mostSimilar)
    {
        suggestItem.Add(lineCount, mostSimilar);
    }
    lineCount++;
    currentSimilar = 0;
}
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add as text what your input is, and what your expected output? It seems to me they have the same key count.

Comment: It's irrelevant of course, but please split message using underscore simply between single quotes and forget .ToCharArray()

Comment: @ZivWeissman The input is here: https://gyazo.com/6cb86e78b95026aeeb3f8cc96ca03163 - it is StatTrak™_Desert_Eagle_|_Golden_Koi_(Factory_New), the console on the left shows the two things returned - it should only find the one with stattrak surely (that is what I want it to do anyway).

Comment: @MachineLearning I have updated this now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rephrase your code (*that looks correct btw*) in a more idiomatic translation

```
var res =suggestContents.Select(
    (x,i) => new Tuple<int, string,int>
    (i, x , message.Split('_')
       .Count(z => x.ToLower().Contains(z.ToLower())))
    ).GroupBy(t => t.Item3).OrderByDescending(t => t.Key).First();
```

You may want to change it to

```
var res = suggestContents.Select(
             (x, i) => new Tuple<int, string, int>
             (i, x, message.Split('_')
                .Count(z => 
                (x.ToLower().Contains(z.ToLower()))
                ||
                 (x.ToLower().Split(' ').Any(w =>
                   z.ToLower().Contains(w.ToLower())))
                ))
             ).GroupBy(t => t.Item3).OrderByDescending(t => t.Key).First();
```

The idea is to test not ony if the line contains a word but also if the word (stattraktm) contains part (stattrakt) of any split of the line.

Comment: Hi - Sorry I went out last night and only just got up this morning. I have just tried it and it still returns two values even when I input the exact string as seen here: https://gyazo.com/89b5ff9453dd62b72f02633e66c6b558 which I could fix but for some reason it messes up for some reason as seen here: https://gyazo.com/57895082af18bdf7b42f4dc930c08cc8 which should display M4A1-S | Cyrex (Field-Tested) but displays some Music Kit that has no relevance. It's weird how this works however: https://gyazo.com/3bfbbc1e1ff1e49b883cd7c67cf515fc . Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I could try and do letter similarities rather than using the .contains method? I am not sure if that wouild be better or not however. By this I mean I could count how many letters in each line and compare it from that so it would get a more precise result?

Comment: The first code is equivalent to yours, with same results, only a confirmation. The second snippet is a modification and should give the expected results... let me look at your link in the next few hours. Thanks. P.S. don't post images but share text format please. See you later

Comment: @CrimpStR Please share - in **text** format, **not** yet another image - the content of the file `csgo_items.txt` (i.e. the `suggestContents` array) and the `message` string. After that, I'll edit my answer in reply to your comments. Thanks again!

Comment: "I could try and do letter similarities rather than using the .contains method?" Not exactly. What I mean is that (based on my understanding of your problem) you're not finding the word `stattraktm` in the line that contains`stattrakt` because there is a `m` missing. So I'm suggesting to check also in the other direction if the words (not the single characters) of the line contain the searched key... A text format example will help to better check and understand

Comment: I have edited my code to use Levenshteins distance and it is working now. Thanks a lot anyway though, your use of lambda inspired me to go and research.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help without seeing your TXT file. It seems strange that your console says stattrakt, yet on the right you can see stattrak™ which is totally different word and will not be a match in .Contain or anything.

Without changing your code much, although I support Machine Learning solution, I prefer keep the answer as close to the original code-

```
string[] suggestContents = File.ReadAllLines("csgo_items.txt");
int lineCount = 0;
int mostSimilar = 0;
int currentSimilar = 0;
string[] splitLine = message.Split("_".ToCharArray());
//Dictionary<int, int> suggestItem = new Dictionary<int, int>();
List<string> suggestedItems = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in suggestContents)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < splitLine.Length; i++)
    {
        if(line.ToLower().Contains(splitLine[i].ToLower()))
        {
            currentSimilar++;
        }
    }
    if(currentSimilar > mostSimilar)
    {
        //We clear the current list, it is no longer needed, we have better match
        //List<int> suggestList = new List<int>();
        suggestedItems.Clear();

        mostSimilar = currentSimilar;

        //add current line to array.
        suggestedItems.Add(line);
    }
    else if(currentSimilar == mostSimilar)
    {
        //if another match simply add to list without clearing it.
        suggestedItems.Add(line);
    }
    lineCount++;
    currentSimilar = 0;
}
```

Might have mistakes cause I did it on the editor here.

Another option might be replacing the foreach with regular for loop, and save the index of the line instead of the line itself if it more important to you in a same way only List of int.

Comment: Thanks for your response, although this still did not give me the result I was looking for. The StatTrakT in console I'm guessing is just a formatting bug. I ended up using Levenshtein's distance and it is working now.